# How to use outline icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use outline icon from material design. How can I do this?

```
Icon(
  Icons.dashboard,
  color: Colors.blue,
  size: 24,
),
```

Example I want to add 'theme: Themes.outline' in the above code. Is it possible to do this?

[image: f]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to my knowledge, flutter material library has a limited amount of outline icons. Check here for the full list of icons: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

But you can also try downloading the outlined icons you wish to use from [Material Design](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline) and convert them into your own custom flutter icons using [FlutterIcon](http://fluttericon.com/).

Use this post on [Medium](https://medium.com/flutterpub/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977) to understand how to use the custom icons from [FlutterIcon](http://fluttericon.com/)

By the way, I also came across this useful package [outline_material_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/outline_material_icons), this should be more useful and helpful in your situation.

Comment: package outline_material_icons is really useful, all icons are outlined. But I noticed that in the source code there is actually only one class which points to the urls for each icon, which means that all icons are fetched from the web. Are they fetched in compile-time or in run time? What if the user doesn't have an internet connection?

Comment: @KirillKarmazin everything is static, so I'd say it's compile time

Comment: outline_material_icons package is outdated

Answer (score 7):

I was doing some tests with the Flutter master channel and it seems there are outline material icons in this channel. However, I haven't found any thread or discussion about this being added in the future to the stable channel

Edit: These icons are now available in stable channel

If you have an icon like this:

```
Icon(Icons.science)
```

it would be:

```
Icon(Icons.science_outlined)
```

I tested some and they seem to work fine

[image: Outlined icons]

Answer (score 2):

You can find icon resources here: https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons

Use the right drawer to get Flutter id.

Comment: This link really should be added to the flutter documentation... makes a world of difference